# Wordpress distinguish between actual pages and products from woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I'm having some trouble separating products and pages in the search results.

This is what I have so far

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'product' ) : ?>
        <div class="woocommerce">
            <h2>Product results</h2>
            <ul class="products cols-4">
                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>
                    <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>
                        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( $post->post_type == 'page' ) : ?>
        <h2>Page results</h2>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php x_get_view( $stack, 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_content-none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I've gotten to the point where I get product results to show up the way I want (so they all show as in the default woocommerce layout). But I can't seem to exclude products from the "page" results. I.e. all the products show up on the page results as well.

Example:

Product results

PRODUCT 1 - PRODUCT 2 - PRODUCT 3 - PRODUCT 4

Page results

PAGE 1 (product 1, already shown above)

PAGE 2 (product 2, already shown above)

PAGE 3 (product 1, already shown above)

PAGE 4 (product 2, already shown above)

I was hoping that

```
if ( $post->post_type == 'page' )
```

would only return actual pages (not products). But no luck.

So my question is as the title states, how do I distinguish between actual pages and products from woocommerce in wordpress for the search results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this before your pages while have_posts

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'post_type' => 'page' ) );
query_posts( $args );
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! That did it. Just out of curiosity, how does that make the while have posts loop only bring out actual pages (and exclude products from woocommerce)?

Comment: Great. The while have_posts loops through the main loop. You need to adjust the main loop arguments with post_type parameter to only pull up 'page' posts and none other. That is what my code does.